# Get Current Principal as my Custom Application User in ASP.Net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

In previous versions of ASP.NET, if I wanted to have a custom class as my current logged in user, what I did was: I let the FormsAuthentication module do its work, and then, in the PostAuthenticateRequest event I replaced the current Principal (HttpContext.Current.User) with my custom principal object that I fetched from the database (with some caching for performance).

How can I achieve the same in ASP.NET Identity? I have my own ApplicationUser (not the default that comes with the EntityFramework ASP.NET Identity) and my own UserStore.

In every authenticated request, I have the HttpContext.User as a ClaimsPrincipal object. Is there a way to replace that with my CustomClaimsPrincipal?

Is there another, better way, to retrieve the current ApplicationUser instance based on the current ClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: Why do you need to replace with `CustomClaimsPrincipal`? what extra are you planning implement?

Comment: @trailmax My custom user has a lot of extra information that I need. So, what is the proper way to handle such situations in asp.net identity core?

Comment: Can't you use `UserManager<YourApplicationUser>.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)` to fetch the current ApplicationUser?

Comment: Are you using (or planning to use) [Microsoft's OWIN](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana) implementation?

Comment: @ckerth yes. I'm using ASP.NET Core. I suppose it uses owin by default?

Comment: You may want to test if adding custom claims with the information you want to provide additionally suffices for your case.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis Hmm, you probably should use my answer only as a general direction. The ASP.Net Core appears to not use the OWIN middleware approach.

Comment: @ckerth Yes, I actually implemented it that way. Every property of my custom user is passed as a claim in the Generic Claims Principal. Whenever I want to read the logged-in user's properties I just access the claims. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have your own `IUserStore` you can implement `IUserClaimStore` to customize the claims identity which is passed to the claims principal.

If you need to replace the default claims principal you should implement the `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` and pass your implementation to the `SignInManager` and register the configured manager to your owin context.

It should look like this along the lines.
(Assuming you are using *ASP.NET Core Identity*, for Identity v2 the interfaces and constructors may differ!)

```
class CustomClaimsFactory<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>
    where TUser : class
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        // create and return your custom principal
    }
}

class OwinStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(CreateSignInManager);
    }

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager CreateSignInManager()
    {
        UserManager manager; // the manager that uses your custom IUserStore
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor; // I don't know where to get it from...

        var factory = new CustomClaimsFactory();
        return new SignInManager(manager, accessor, factory, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**For ASP.Net Core** the OWIN-like startup configuration is done via [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).